# How to describe absence of value in dart?

Tags: dart

In the turnary operator statement `5 == 5 ? print('Correct') : print('Wrong')`, I want the statement to return nothing(You can see it's returning a print statement) if the evaluation of the initial expression turns false, how do I do that?

The actual code is given below, the return type cannot be null. So, that isn't an option

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
   children: <Widget>[
     Text(times[index]),
     newMessagehasCome ? Icon(Icons.laptop) ? 
   ], 
)
```

Comment: Can you give a more complete example which shows the context of your statement?

Comment: The return happen only if a return is placed right before start of ternary operator. In this case, this just simply executes the expression based on evaluation of ternary operator condition.

Comment: by returning, I mean doing nothing, like literally, do nothing. Just like an if block without an else or else if statement

Comment: I've edited the post with my actual problem, check it out!

Comment: You need to use a if here inside the collection definition. See chapter two here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d

Comment: @julemand101 but flutter says that if, for statements are not allowed in the current version of dart sdk that I'm using, any help?

Comment: Can you try run the flutter doctor and see what version of the Dart SDK you are using?

Comment: 'The for, if, and spread elements weren't supported until version 2.3.0, but this code is required to be able to run on earlier versions.
Try updating the SDK constraints.' - That's what it says. I'm on dart 2.7.2 btw

Comment: Ok, so you SDK supports the feature but in your `pubspec.yaml` file you have properly set you supported sdk to a version lower than 2.3.0. Try update it so minimum version are 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this if you project supports Dart 2.3.0 or later:

```
Column(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
   children: <Widget>[
     Text(times[index]),
     if (newMessagehasCome)
       Icon(Icons.laptop)
   ], 
)
```